# Saving read/unread state in listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a app that can reserve message from php server and append new message in listView,
then mark a point on that item to show unread,of course it will disappear when click the item,
these is my question:

how can i save the read/unread mark on each item in order to when i login the app next time i
 still can see the mark.

I have tried using share preference but it seems not a good solution.there is so may key to save and it's inconvenient when modify the value.

is it need SQLite ?  or have easier solution? need some to help.

Comment: SQLite is indeed a good solution +1

Comment: Yes if you use SQLite then you can share one of the identifiers of the post (say some Id or maybe the url of that post) along with the read/unread status. Next time while loading the list view you can apply the required read/unread effects by reading from your DB. If the server too is in your control, then I would suggest to send  the read/unread status to your server itself and store it there, and return this status as response to the client. This way the status will be reflected in any of clients from where the user logs in.